# Orbeon integration with OIDC Provider

Tags: keycloak, orbeon

I am trying to integrate Orbeon forms with my auth platform, which is KeyCloak to authenticate and authorize users. Basically I need to protect the forms with KeyCloak and need to use the roles in Orbeon Forms.

I am using latest using Orbeon CE (2019.2).

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 parts to this setup; you need to install and configure the Keycloak server, configure your application server or servlet container, and enable authentication in Orbeon Forms:

1. First, you'll want to install the Keycloak server. You will find information about this on [Server installation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/), part of the Keycloak documentation.
2. Then, you'll need to setup the application server or servlet container you are using to run Orbeon Forms. For instance, with Tomcat, you'll want to [setup the Keycloak Valve](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_tomcat_adapter).
3. Finally, with Orbeon Forms, you'll want to setup [container-driven authentication](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/access-control/users#container-driven-method).

Comment: Thanks @avernet , I followed those steps, and I am getting 403 while accessing the form. If the user is not logged in, I am redirected to KeyCloak login and on successful authentication it takes me to 403 page. I have cross-checked the role names and it matches with what's in Keycloak with the orbeon web.xml.

Comment: Here is what I did; 
1) Added a context.xml in orbeon/META-INF folder to use the Keycloak Authenticator Valve. And added keycloak adapter dependencies.
2) Added keycloak.json (we have an existing keycloak installation) under orbeon/WEB-INF folder
3) Modified the orbeon/WEB-INF/web.xml to use the security-constraint with role (staff), and login-config as BASIC
4) Modified the properties-local file to use container auth and listed roles (staff)
Can you please confirm if I am missing any steps?